# Android change of view failing

Tags: android, view

I have a function that does a POST request, and when it finishes, I want the view to be changed. To do so, I have the following code:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    final Button button_modificar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_modificar);
    button_modificar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                new SendPostRequest().execute();

                Intent intent2 = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Main_esp_Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

I do not know why it crashes, when I delete the lines: 
`Intent intent2 = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Main_esp_Activity.class);      startActivity(intent2);`, it works perfectly. I would be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: This code will not behave as you expect. You need to trigger an asynchronous operation and perform your view changes in the callback. You code here will immediately try to launch a new activity right after `SendPostRequest.execute()` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all sou much for your answers and time. I have just came out with a solution to the problem: the activity "Main_esp_Activity" had the following lines of code: 
`Intent intentGetUser = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intentGetUser.getExtras();
user = extras.getString("user");`

Which where used to get the "user" string value of the previous activity. So what I had to do was just passing a value back of the string "user" to the "Main_esp_Activity, so the final code changes in the following:

```
Intent intentt = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Main_esp_Activity.class);
intentt.putExtra("user", user);
startActivity(intentt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the Activity you want to open with your intent is declared in Manifest file? if it is not then declare it like the Main Activity

May be this help you.

Answer (score 0):

call this piece code in onPostExecute()!

```
Intent intent2 = new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Main_esp_Activity.class);
startActivity(intent2);
```